# Track changes to particular div without using onclick functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

I am using jquery to implement some functionality that is repeated multiple place in the same jsp. I want to re-use the same jquery code again. Can anyone let me know how can I achieve that? Hope the below code snippet explain what I really want to achieve.

```
        <div id="1" class="a">
         //implement the some functionality to all the 
elements that below to this class and id="1"
        </div>


        <div id="2" class="a">
    //implement the similar functionality that is happening 
int above div to all the elements that below to this class and id="2"
        </div>


        <div id="3" class="a">
    //implement the similar functionality that is happening 
int above div to all the elements that below to this class and id="2"
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //Re-usable code goes here that applies for class type 2 and tracks id 1,2,3 differently.
</script>
```

**Edit**

I want to use datatable at multiple places in the same html page and at each instance of the datatable used, I want to do similar customization using Jquery.

https://datatables.net/examples/

Comment: What do you mean by `track change`? Any HTML change inside these DIVs? I guess if you provide concrete sample of what you are looking for, your question would be clearer

Comment: yes, I have a piece of code(data table grid  to be precise ) that gets executed on button click.. the button and all stuff related the table are inside divs 1,2,3, now, I want to re-use the code over and over again.

Comment: So instead ask question relevant to your issue, not the workaround you think would fix it. Anyway, i still don't understand what you are looking for. Maybe as suggested in answer below, you are just looking for a common selector for click event, and maybe delegating it. But i'm not sure how is it related to datatable plugin nor jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. When any element with id 1,2 or 3 is clicked, then it will execute the same function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#1, #2, #3', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target); // This is the element that was clicked
   alert('Clicked')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cnLvk3o1/1/

If you want to select by class like A.Wolff has mentioned below. You can use this instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.a', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target); // This is the element that was clicked
   alert('Clicked')
});
```

Comment: But then why not using `.a` as selector?

Comment: @A.Wolff, you're right, that's what I would do. I just don't know what they want.

Comment: @yeppe, I'm not quite sure I understand what your question in that case.

Comment: Why don't you just do your setup in this: `$(document).ready(function() { })`?